# Lookup HashTable key, value pairs after loading SavedModel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, hashtable

I have initialized a simple `HashTable` in Tensorflow and saved the model using **SavedModelBuilder**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    file_name = tf.constant("vocab_target.txt", tf.string)

    id_to_vocab_init = tf.contrib.lookup.TextFileStringTableInitializer(
        file_name,
        key_column_index=1,
        value_column_index=0,
        vocab_size=None,
        delimiter='\t',
    )

    id_to_vocab_table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(id_to_vocab_init, "UNK")

    indices = tf.constant([1, 2], tf.int64)
    values = id_to_vocab_table.lookup(indices)

    init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)

    print(values.eval())

    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('./export/')
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["serve"], legacy_init_op=init_op)
    builder.save()
```

Before saving, I can easily lookup the values using `id_to_vocab_table.lookup`

Now, after loading the saved model,

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], './export/')
```

How can I query/Lookup the HashTable similarly?

(to say, how can I access that HashTable object after loading SavedModel)

**Follow-ups:**
How could I initialize the table if it does not have any `<key, value>` pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Adds the `signature_def_map` argument when invoke `add_meta_graph_and_variables()` method. The input and output of the signature could be constracted by `tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(tensor)` and the tensors are `indices` and `values` respectively.

After get and load the savedmodel, use `sess.run()` as usual:

```
indices_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(indices_tensor_name)
values_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(values_tensor_name)
sess.run([values_tensor],feed_dict={indices_tensor : [${real_data}]})
```